# Conditional Probability, Lack of Dependence on a Parameter

Tags: probability, information-theory

I am trying to understand why the following is true:
$$
p(f(Y) = f(y) \mid Y = y) = p(f(Y) = f(y) \mid X = x, Y = y) \qquad \ldots \text{(Eq. 1)}
$$
where $Y$ and $X$ are random variables, and $f(Y)$ is a function of a random variable. $p(Y = y)$ represents the probability density function of random variable $Y$, evaluated at the point $y$.

Equation 1 states the event $f(Y) = f(y)$ conditioned on the value of the random variable $Y$, has no dependence, or is unaffected by the value of random variable $X$. Is there a formal name for Equation 1, or any additional information to help me understand further the process behind Equation 1?

The context for my question is Markov Chains in Information Theory. $X$, $Y$, and $f(Y)$ form a Markov Chain in That Order. Equation 1 must be true to imply the Markov Chain of the three random variables.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it specified that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: @snarski: There is no requirement that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: I don't understand the notation. As it's written, $p(f(Y)=f(y)∣Y=y)=1$ trivially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(Y)$ depends on $Y$, and $X$ depends on $Y$, and $f(Y)$ is **conditionally independent** of $X$ given $Y$ due to your Markov Chain assumption. Therefore, $p(f(Y)|X,Y) = p(f(Y)|Y)$. In general this is not true, rather $p(f(Y)|X,Y) = \int p(f(Y)|X,Y) p(X|Y) \mathrm{d}X$

Comment: The way I see it is: If the conditional distribution of $Z$ given $X$ and $Y$ is the same as the conditional distribution of $Z$ which depends only on $Y$, then $X$, $Y$, $Z$ form a Markov chain in that order. If $p(Z\mid X,Y) = p(Z\mid Y)$, then the Markov chain is formed. If $Z = f(Y)$ and $Y$ is known, then our characterization of $f(Y)$ knowing the additional information $X$ is the same as the characterization not knowing $X$ since $Z$ is a deterministic function of only the random variable $Y$.